# Update (re-deploy) existing azure webjob

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I created an on-demand webjob. In the management portal there is no option to upload a new zip, to update it.
I can delete the existing webjob and create a new one, but I would like to keep my logs.
Is there any way to re-deploy it, overriding the old version, maintaining the logs?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can connect to the website where the webjob is at via FTP and update the necessary files without erasing your log files.

You can get the credentials to connect via FTP from the Publish Profile.

**UPDATE**

Added screenshot to find credentiales easier per Erik's comment
[image]

Comment: It works, the path is:  `/site/www-root/App_Data/jobs/triggered/{JobName}/`

Comment: The FTP credentials in the Azure App Service are now under Deployment Center -> FTPS Credentials tab (as of 9/2022)

Answer (score 20):

You can also use your website's debug console at: https://yoursitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole
There you get a file explorer in your browser where you can drag/drop files (even zips that will be extracted into your website).

In the file browser go to d:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\triggered\jobname

Some more info about this at: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/74215124623/deploy-azure-webjobs/

Comment: if it's a continuous webjob the path is : D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\continuous\jobname