# How to publish the latest source of a WebJob?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-webjobs

'Publish as AzureWebJob' from Visual Studio doesn't overwrite the existing WebJob. (The 'settings.job' file gets overwritten however.)

The old sample code from the VS project template had a method named 'ProcessQueueMessage' in a file called 'Funtions'. I don't get the expected result during execution, and the log file states:

"Found the following functions:
DocumentDbSync.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage"

but the 'ProcessQueueMessage' method is long gone. I've even tried to delete the WebJob using the portal, and re-deploy, without any luck.

Comment: Please check using [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) whether the issue is indeed that the files are not getting deployed, versus some other condition. They should get deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had changed the namespace and assembly name, but didn't clear the bin sub-folders.

Due to ordering (probably alphabetic), WebJobs picked up the old assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Publishing from Visual Studio should work. However, there are a couple of ways in which you can redeploy without using Visual Studio.

1. An option is to connect to the site using FTP. Checkout [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448427/update-re-deploy-existing-azure-webjob/28453226#28453226) Basically connect via FTP using the credentials found in your Publish Profile.
2. Another option is to connect using **Kudu**. You can do this be going to this url:

> https://yourwebsitename.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole

[image: Kudu snapshot]

You can modify the file accordingly using the UI.

3. Finally you can always upload/delete your WebJob from the Azure Portal.